# table overflow when using PERFORM VARYING

Tags: cobol

I'm doing a simple PERFORM VARYING WS-IND FROM 1 BY 1

Bellow is my code:

```
       PERFORM VARYING WS-INDICE FROM 1 BY 1
       UNTIL WS-INDICE > 9
       OR TEST-OBJEC(WS-INDICE) = SPACES
           MOVE TEST-OBJEC(WS-INDICE) TO WS-VAL-OBJEC(WS-INDICE)
           MOVE TEST-DATE(WS-INDICE)  TO WS-DAT-OBJEC(WS-INDICE)
       END-PERFORM
```

Index was declared like this:

```
01  WS-INDICE PIC 9(01).
```

Bellow the declaration of my array

```
          10        TEST-GROUP
                           OCCURS 009.
           15       TEST-OBJEC  PICTURE X(01).
           15       TEST-DATE   PICTURE X(8).
          10        FILLER PICTURE X(56).
```

My problem that the WS-INDICE arrive until 9 and restart from 0.

Comment: Please include the note which compiler is used - I'd guess: ACUCOBOL-GT, please adjust the question.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know wich compiler i'm using. If this compiler is used, how i can fix this issue please ?

Comment: Do you know how you compile the code? In this case we should be able to find the answer (if you can execute it: passing either `-V` or `-v` often outputs its name/version)

Comment: ... if you get a SOC07 then it is most likely _some_ version of IBM COBOL (check the listing / output to get the version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem description**

> the WS-INDICE arrive until 9 and restart from 0

**Code**

```
VARYING WS-INDICE FROM 1 BY 1
        UNTIL WS-INDICE > 9
```

**Problem reason**

A compiler that both does not warn about conditions that may never be true and additional also overflows (the COBOL standard says "raise exception and don't change value").

... because of the definition `WS-INDICE PIC 9(01).`

This variable cannot hold more than one digit should never be greater than 9 (leaving out the possibility that someone moves `x'99'` to that, inserting invalid data).

Adjust the definition to use a `PIC 99` and everything is fine.
And possibly consider to use constants instead:

```
          10        TEST-GROUP
-                          OCCURS 009.
+                          OCCURS WS-INDICE-MAX.

        PERFORM VARYING WS-INDICE FROM 1 BY 1
-       UNTIL WS-INDICE > 9
+       UNTIL WS-INDICE > WS-INDICE-MAX
```

For this to work you'd need support for either a common PC extension "level 78 constants" or a compiler that supports "COBOL 2002 constants":

```
       78  WS-INDICE-MAX    VALUE 9.
       01  integer-constant CONSTANT AS 9.
```

... and possibly consider to use another compiler for better warnings (you don't need to use that otherwise), for example with GnuCOBOL 3+ and `cobc -W -frelax-syntax-checks -fsyntax-only`:

> warning: 'WS-INDICE' may not be GREATER THAN 9